# navigator set to full range

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

How I can set navigator to display only few data. Navigator is set in full range but I want to show only two data and rest of the data I want to see by scrolling navigator. I am adding js fiddle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/9y91y3s9/

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div class="row">
            <highchart id="chart1" config="mtv" class="span10"></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h3><a href="https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng">See Highcharts-ng on github</a></h3>
```

**JavaScript:** (see https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.mtv = {

        useHighStocks: true,
        options: {
            xAxis: {
                type: "datetime",
                plotLines: [],
            },
            title: {
                text: 'fssfgdf'
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: false
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'gddfdg',
            data: [
                [1435324350703, 1],
                [1435324365737, 1],
                [1435324395659, 1],
                [1435324410674, 1]
            ],
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius: 3
            },
        }],
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`, for example:

```
        xAxis: {
            min: 1435324395659,
            max: 1435324410674,
            type: "datetime",
            plotLines: [],
        }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9y91y3s9/1/

Comment: in my case data is coming from  array so do you know how i can get only x value from that .

Comment: Set max and min as last two x-value from that arrays?